# How to set the color of a cell or range to transparent?

Tags: spreadsheetgear

I know how to set the color to red for example:

```
row.Interior.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0);
```

But how to set the background to transparent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by using System.Drawing.Color instead of Spreadsheetgear.Drawing.Color:

```
row.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
```